# The difference between “elect" and "select"

Tags: meaning, grammar

What is the difference between “elected” and “selected”?
When something is selected there is only one determinate factor and that is "choice". When something is elected there is more than one determining factor or a group. When politicians are elected, it's based on a consensus...they cannot be randomly selected by anyone or any group.

Comment: What did you find in a dictionary and why does that not answer the question? Presenting your own research saves anyone else repeating it unnecessarily. (In expanding the question, please click *Edit* and edit the new data in. Do include a link to an online dictionary, if you used one.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have some doubt for this . Is it any tens related words ?

Comment: "Is it any tens related words?" doesn't make any sense. You might be interested in a related site: [ell.se]

Comment: "selection" is *specific* and *determinate*, while "election" is not determinate.  When you elect a thing, it is your choice, but that outcome is not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "Elect" is about choosing somebody to do a particular job by voting, but the word "select" is about choosing somebody or something according to a system.

As a rule, simply remember if a person is required for a post and he or she will be elected via votes, then you have to use "elect", otherwise use "select".

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

`Elected` (To Elect) is more of a political word, E.g "For some unknown reason we had elected GW Bush to be the president of the United States of America."

`Selected`(To Select) is used for more common choices. E.g "Please could you select from one of the choices listed above"

Comment: -1 There are many cases in politics where people are *selected* for a job; e.g. those appointed directly by a president of prime minister are *selected* - not *elected*.  And there are many non-political positions, e.g. those running a small charity, who my be *elected* by the members.

Comment: I stated. "is MORE" not absolute. GW Bush was elected. The people elected GW Bush, Bush selected his team.

Comment: Side note - (To Elect) - The name that is used `Elections` (a formal and organized process of electing or being elected, esp. of members of a political body.)

Comment: And I disagree that it is "a political word" *in any sense*. The fact that elections do happen in politics doesn't make it "more of a political word". As you've agreed selections also happen in politics. And elections also happen outside politics.

Comment: Most people will correlate (To Elect) from a political point of view, more so in the USA. Of course it can be even used within a class room to elect a class president, nothing to do with politics. (Latin Eligere > Elect). (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elect?q=elect)

Comment: Your link provides 7 example phrases using elect - 2 of them are related to politics; 5 of them are non-political! I think you've disproved your point that "Elected ... is more of a political word". (I can't speak for the connotation within the USA.)

Comment: That makes no sense, just because there are 2 examples does not mean it is not popular. I can speak from the USA's perspective as I have worked there. (Elect - Political / Appoint - Business). Of course there are exceptions as I have stated above. Not all words carry equal weight.

Comment: You seem to have changed from "more political" to "popular". I said nothing about popularity. I agree it's commonly used in a political context. I understand "more of a political word" to mean *has political connotations*. Its common usage in a political context does not - to my mind - mean that it has political connotations, any more than "president" is "more of a political word" because it is often used to refer to the President of the USA. My point is that, on their own, both "elect" and "president" are neutral with no *inherent* political connotations, despite their common usage.

Comment: Correction, "more political (meaning used more in the political world). When have you ever read that a new president has been selected? I respect you point of view. As you do mine.